# Way to dynamically get repositories without a dependency on a DI container

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

I have a class that returns a repository (read only) using a generic method this is to reduce the number of repository classes I need to inject into classes in my business layer. It also allows me to add and use a new repo anywhere I have this wrapper class simply by adding a repo which implements `IGenericReadRepo<T>` as this will be registered in unity using the line  `Container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericReadRepository<>), typeof(GenericReadRepository<>), new TransientLifetimeManager());`. However this has is dependent on unity being the DI container. This smells to me.

```
public class ReadRepositoryWrapper : IReadRepositoryWrapper
{
    private IUnityContainer _unityContainer;

    public ReadRepositoryWrapper(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _unityContainer = container;
    }

    public IGenericReadRepository<T> GetReadRepository<T>() where T : class
    {
         return _unityContainer.Resolve<IGenericReadRepository<T>>();
    }
}
```

Can anyone think of a way to implement the `GetReadRepository<T>` without a the dependency on unity while not introducing any new dependencies. Or can someone think of another way to get repositories without having bloated constructors or a dependency on my context.

Comment: Passing in the DI container is an anti-pattern (no matter what DI library is used).  Typically the constructor will take parameters for all the objects it will need to reference, some of those objects may be factories that know how to construct other objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create generic factory interfaces/classes for dynamic object creation. Many DI containers support object creation using lambda expressions.

```
public interface IFactory<T>
{
  T Create();
}

public class Factory<T> : IFactory<T>
{
  private readonly Func<T> _creator;

  public Factory(Func<T> creator)
  {
    if(creator == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("creator");

    _creator = creator;
  }

  public T Create()
  {
    return _creator();
  }
}
```

The generic factory interface than can be injected into the consuming classes.

```
public class ReadRepositoryWrapper<T> : IReadRepositoryWrapper<T> where T : class
{
  private readonly IFactory<IGenericReadRepository<T>> _factory;

  public ReadRepositoryWrapper(IFactory<IGenericReadRepository<T>> factory)
  {
    if(factory == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("factory");

    _factory = factory;
  }

  public IGenericReadRepository<T> GetReadRepository()
  {
    return _factory.Create();
  }
}
```

Or something like that.